# Check if object property value is false

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

I can't seem to find the explanation of how to check if a property value in an object is false. I have this code where I try to check if property 'active' is false but only the `typeof data[i].active ==='undefined` part works.

```
function createHTML(data) {
var myTable = document.getElementById('list');    
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var row = myTable.insertRow();
    for (var key in data[i]) {                
            var cell = row.insertCell();                
            if (data[i].hasOwnProperty(key) ) {                    
                cell.innerHTML = data[i][key];                    
                    if(typeof data[i].active === false || typeof 
                       data[i].active ==='undefined')  {
                        cell.innerHTML+= "<span class='eye'><i class='fa fa-
                        eye-slash'></i></span>";                             
                    } 
                }
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *logical not* operator:

```
if (!data[i].active) {
  // data[i].active is false, 0, undefined, null
}
```

> Returns false if its single operand can't be converted to true; otherwise, returns true.

Answer (score 2):

`null`, `undefined`, `0`, `''`, `false` are evaluated as **falsey** values inside `if` statements.

In your case we can turn your problem in this way:

is `data[i].active` a `falsey` value?

to improve readability you can create helper functions:

```js
function isActive(item) { return item && !!item.active; }
function isNotActive(item) { return !isActive(item); }
```

now you can change your code:

```js
if(
  typeof data[i].active === false || 
  typeof data[i].active ==='undefined'
)  {}

if(isNotActive(data[i]))  {}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check only for the **false**, not all the falsy value like null, undefined, 0 etc, then use **=== (triple equals)**.

So you code becomes

```
if(data[i].active === false)  {
   cell.innerHTML+= "<span class='eye'><i class='fa fa-
   eye-slash'></i></span>";                             
 }
```